# Rails CanCan(Can) complex authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

I have the following models:

```
class User
  has_many :videos
  has_many :videos_shared_by, class_name: "SharedVideo", foreign_key: "shared_by_id"
  has_many :videos_shared_to, class_name: "SharedVideo", foreign_key: "shared_to_id"

  has_many :followee_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_many :follower_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followee_id"

  has_many :following, through: :followee_relationships, source: :followee
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :blocked_followee_relationships, -> { blocked }, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_many :blocked_follower_relationships, -> { blocked }, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followee_id"

  has_many :blocking, through: :blocked_followee_relationships, source: :followee
  has_many :blockers, through: :blocked_follower_relationships, source: :follower
end

class Video
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :shares, class_name: "SharedVideo"
  has_many :shared_to, through: :shares, source: :shared_to
  has_many :shared_by, through: :shares, source: :shared_by

  has_many :reviews

  has_many :blocking, through: :user
  has_many :blockers, through: :user

  def private?
   !public?
  end
end

class Review
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :linked_reivew, class_name: "Review"
end

class SharedVideo
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :shared_by, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :shared_to, class_name: "User"
end
```

I think everything is fairly self explanatory except for the `linked_review` association in the Review model. Any two reviews can link to each other essentially creating what I refer to as a Dual Review.

In my CanCan abilities class I started with the following rules:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :read, Video, public: true
    can :read, Video, shared_to: { id: user.id }

    # can :read, Video, if indirectly accessible through linked review (see comments below)

    cannot :read, Video, blocking: { id: user.id }
    cannot :read, Video, blockers: { id: user.id }

    can [:read, :update, :destroy], Video, user_id: user.id

  end
end
```

These work as expected but I can't seem to figure out how to grant read access to a video that a user has access to indirectly through a linked review.

In other words, if user-a is requesting access to video #2 (private, not shared and owned by user-b) and video #2 is associated with video #1 (accessible to user-a because it's public, shared with him or owned by him) via a linked review, then I want the requesting user to be granted read access.

Any ideas on how I can do this? A block doesn't work because CanCan ignores blocks for the index action i.e. when it calls `Video.accessible_by(current_ability)`. I've tried to figure out some kind of scope for the video model but just can't seem to wrap my head around how I would do this.